# Writing a function that checks prime numbers

Tags: python

```
def primecheck(num): 
if num > 1:  
    for i in range(2, num): 
        if (num % i) == 0: 
            return False 
            break
        else: 
            return True
```

Im trying to make a function that checks if an input is prime or not. This code does return True if I enter a prime number, but it also enters true whenever I enter a multiple of a prime number? Why is this happening

thanks

Comment: It should only return True if all numbers in range were checked that they can't divide num.

Comment: What input is this not working for?

Comment: @BilltheLizard as I said, multiples of primes, like 15, 35, 49 etc

Comment: After `return` code stopped, so your `i` became 2 then it returned either in if or in else block. So only `i` which you check is 2. Your should return True only after the for block.

Comment: Problem is with your if-else..  Suppose, your number is 15. Then from 2 to 14,  for loop will execute. So for the first time only (15%2!=0) so it will go in else statement and return True without executing loop further.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you have `return` statements in the first iteration of the loop. Also `break` statement is not needed. Moving `return True` outside the loop gives the solution:

```py
def primecheck(num):
    for i in range(2, num):
       if num % i == 0:
           return False
    return True
```

I leave `num` = 0 or 1 for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using **return** in the **else** part. So your code will break after 1st iteration and print the result of first iteration.

You can do something like this:

```
def primecheck(num): 
    if num > 1:  
        for i in range(2, num): 

            if (num % i) == 0: 
                return False

        return True          

print(primecheck(15))
```

Comment: You can remove `break`, `else:`, and `continue`. They only make the code messier.

Comment: @rpoleski  Agreed

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply use for else for this.

```
def primecheck(num):
   if num>1:
      for i in range(2, num):
           if num%i==0:
                return False
                break
      else:
           return True
print(primecheck(15))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `else` statement, no need for it. And also `break` is not needed

```
def primecheck(num):
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, num):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                return False
    return True
```

or you can solve it **without any iterations**. You can use [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) to solve this easily(hope you refer it),

```
def primeChecker(n):
    m = 2   #can be any number
    if(n > 1):
        if (((m**n)-m)%n == 0):  #Using Fermat's little theorem
            return True
    return False


n = int(input());
if primeChecker(n):
    print('{} - is prime number'.format(n))
else:
    print('{} - NOT a prime number'.format(n))
```

Doing a little research on the internet will help to solve these types of questions much easier and efficiently. ;). Cheers!